# Converting image to text using pytesseracct

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, tesseract, python-tesseract, text-recognition

I want to extract digits from this image.

[image]

I have used opencv to preprocess the image using this code snippet

```
def inverte(imagem):
    imagem = (255-imagem)
    return imagem

import cv2
image = cv2.imread('5.jpg', 0)
print(image)
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
thresh=inverte(thresh)
```

The output of this code is this

[image]

Now after that I am using tesseract to get the text from this image using this code

```
import pytesseract
image=cv2.imread("output.png")
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
custom_config = r'--psm 13 --oem 1 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'
results = pytesseract.image_to_string(rgb,lang='eng',config=custom_config)
print(results)
```

I have tried all valid psm values and oem values but it not giving correct result

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the followings:

- [Image-thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)
- [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)

You have already know the page-segmentation-modes, therefore I don't need to recommend it.

One way to recognize the text is applying threshold to the image. You have three-options

- [Simple-threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)
- [Adaptive-threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)
- [Threshold using cv2.inRange](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html)

You have already applied simple-threshold and couldn't get the desired result. Next you can apply `adaptive-threshold` which will be:

[image]

Now if you read it with your current configuration:

```
607
```

Unfortunately digit 9 is not recognized.

If we try `inRange` threshold:

[image]

Now if you read it with your current configuration:

```
607
```

Code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("EkXoW.jpg")

# Convert to the gray-scale
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Convert to the HSV color
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Adaptive-threshold
thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry, 255,
                            cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 13, 10)

# Threshold-in-range
thr_in_range = cv2.inRange(hsv,
                           np.array([0, 0, 0]),
                           np.array([179, 255, 185]))

# OCR
print("Threshold-in-range result")
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(thr_in_range,
                                  config="--psm 13 --oem 1 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789"))

print("Adaptive threshold result")
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(thr,
                                  config="--psm 13 --oem 1 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789"))

# Display
cv2.imshow("Threshold-in-range result", thr_in_range)
cv2.imshow("Adaptive threshold result", thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

You can get the same results in [0.3.7](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/)

This answer is more of a small-tutorial for image-processing in text recognition than a complete-answer. The reason is the digit-nine is not recognized. Still, I think the explanation contains brief information and useful links which might encourage you to recognize the digit-nine.

Comment: Hello I have tried all the possible image processing techniques but tesseract  as mentioned by you even then it is not giving correct result